# Translate a web page on Android from / to English

Tags: android, offline, web-browser, translation

I need a software that can help me translate web pages **from English to other languages** and **from other languages to English**. The software should

- Have a short way of transferring the web page data to the app. (I don't want to have to copy and paste the entire web page to the app.)
- Be able to translate saved web pages offline.
- Have a dictionary to check the validity of the translated words.

(The software can also be a browser that has translation ability.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome on android will do this natively *to* the language you have set as your native language

[image]
[image]

You can copy and paste the link to google translate to get it the other way around, and it will take a bare URL.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Google translate [also supports downloading offline language files for offline translation](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57576627-285/use-google-translate-offline-by-downloading-language-packs/) on newer versions of android- go to settings, "Manage offline languages" to install the language packs

I have no idea how to save a webpage in android, so I'm afraid I haven't tested that, but comment on how to do so and I'll see if I can test it out

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Web Translator Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.sakura.knatt.webtranslatorlite&hl=en) which allows you to use the "share" feature from your web browser to translate a website. So long as you have some way to "share" an offline webpage, you can translate it. I don't believe that this app has a dictionary however.

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2] [image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Does it fit the requirement "Be able to translate saved web pages offline"?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes so long as you have someway to open up this webpage and share it.

Answer (score 2):

For a browser add-on, you can try an extension for [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&hl=en), called [Dolphin Translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.DolphinTranslate&hl=en). This add-on allows you to translate any webpage into various languages right from your browser as it uses the Google translate API.

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: It does not fit the requirement "Be able to translate saved web pages offline".

Answer (score 1):

PROMT's **[Online-Translator.com](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.promt.pmtappfree)** might be what you're after:

- *Have a shorter of way of transferring the web page data to the app:* Simply enter the URL (see first screenshot)
- *Be able to translate offline saved web pages:* Ooops, got me. I'm not sure here, never tried that.
- *Have a dictionary to check the validity of the translated words:* You can use the integrated "Phrasebook" (second screenshot), but it also has dictionaries with grammar, phonetic and audio pronunciation.

With some (paid) addons, the app can be used even offline. It also supports voice input ­– and output (have the translation spoken via TTS). The big plus are its specialized dictionaries ("Topics" or "Categories"; they call it "Domain specific translation"), which allow for a much more accurate translation. I use their online service for a long time now (though I discovered the app only shortly), and am quite fond of it.

[image: Search] [image: Phrasebook] [image: Speak it!]
<sup>Search, Phrasebook, Translation (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>